# sqlalchemy to_sql if_exists = "replace" creates a table with different prefix

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, ssms

When I try to execute the following code, it drops the actual table in the database but doesn't recreate the same one. Instead of generating the **dbo.TableName** type, it does create **username/TableName**.

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    "mssql+pyodbc://server/dbname?driver=ODBC+Driver+13+for+SQL+Server")
df.to_sql("OTD_1_DELIVERY_TRACKING_F_IMPORT", con=engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this so it recreates the **dbo.TableName** table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does anyone know how to fix this so it recreates the dbo.TableName table

This is happening because the user has a default schema other than `dbo`.  In very old versions of SQL Server each user had their own schema, and this is a vestige of that behavior.

So when that user runs

```
DROP TABLE OTD_1_DELIVERY_TRACKING_F_IMPORT
```

It looks in the user's default schema first, and not finding anything, then looks in the `dbo` schema, and drops that table.  But when the user runs

```
CREATE TABLE OTD_1_DELIVERY_TRACKING_F_IMPORT ...
```

It's created in the user's default schema.

The easy fix is to change the user's DEFAULT SCHEMA to dbo.  EG

```
ALTER USER [SomeUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;
```

Comment: It worked, I had to put my username in brackets [] because it have a backslash, but it worked just fine afterward. Thanks a lot!